# Howto "virtually" create and save an attribute of a separate model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The title may appear as if I am asking howto access/find/update an attribute of a related/nested model but this is not the case and unfortunately this is the best title I could figure out.

I would like to build a soccer management game with ruby on rails, where routine total_attack_value and total_defense_values are matched etc. I don't plan to make the simulation too deep like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427043/soccer-simulation-for-a-game) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192147/how-the-dynamics-of-a-sports-simulation-game-works), such as calculating and matching separate corner_attack or side_attack values but seriously intend to include the goalkeeper's skill in total_defense_value.

To clarify, the total_attack_value is going to be calculated as "total_shooting_value x total_pass_value x total_possess_value x/+ Rand() etc" and all of these ..._values are going to be calculated inside the Team model but the total_defense_value should have "goalkeeper_skill_value" which is going to be the skill of the player selected as the goalkeeper by the user for the coming match, as I planned.

I cannot think of anything else than saving and retrieving which player is put into goalkeeper position by the user using virtual attributes, since the user is going to schedule the match for a future time and the goalkeeper selection should persist until then. In this case I'm going to create a Player_Position model and an association model belonging to both Position and Player and an assign_positions function in Player model etc. **However this is exactly what I am trying to avoid, code- and complexity-wise being the same as to offer the user the possibility to drag&drop players to positions separately as seen in some games** like soccermanager and goalunited.

Does rails offer any simple/ready solution to this problem as it does to simple CRUD operations, like an attribute or STI?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand what you are trying to achieve but the next version of Rails, 3.2, has simple Key Value Store functionality that you may be able to use. The release candidate is already out so you would be able to try it out to see if it met your needs.

A short note on the functionality was included in the [latest release notes](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/12/20/rails-3-2-rc1-faster-dev-mode-routing-explain-queries-tagged-logger-store).